# I've been getting a runtime error on this code snippet for Quicksort and cannot figure out what the problem is

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I'm writing the partition function for quicksort and am getting a runtime error. The problem may be very trivial but for the life of me I cannot seem to find it.

My code is as follows:

```
int partition(int input[],int start,int end)
{   
    int pivotele=input[start];
    int countofsmall=0;
    //counting elements smaller than pivot
    for(int i=1;i<=end;i++)
    {   
        if(input[i]<=pivotele)
        {   
            countofsmall++;
        }   
    }   
    
    int pivot=start+countofsmall;
    //swapping pivot to required place
    int temp=pivotele; //unnecessary but I was testing things
    input[start]=input[pivot];
    input[pivot]=temp;
    
    //rearrange all elements w.r.t. pivot
    int i=start;
    int j=end;
    while(i<pivot && j>pivot)
    {   
        if(input[i]<=pivotele)
        {   
            i++;
        }   
        else if(input[j]>pivotele)
        {   
            j--;
        }   
        else
        {   
            int temp2=input[i];
            input[i]=input[j];
            input[j]=temp2;
            i++;
            j--;
        }   
    }   
    
    //return pivot position
    return pivot;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the runtime error happening when you step through the code in debugger?

Comment: you seem to use `end` as tha last valid index of the array. That's possible, but a little bit unusual, and with an array of size 10, you have to call `partition( input, 0, 9 );`.

Comment: Can you include the `main()` function you're using as well as the args being passed to this function?

Answer (score 0):

its tough to answer this question well without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or a better description about the runtime error you're getting.

I can see one bug though that might cause some funny behavior. I think this loop iterates over the wrong parts of the array:

```
for(int i=1;i<=end;i++)
    {   
        if(input[i]<=pivotele)
        {   
            countofsmall++;
        }   
    }
```

I think the loop should look like this:

```
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
```

The reason is, this is supposed to figure out where the pivot's new index into the array is right? But if start is anything but 0, its possible for `pivot` to be out of bounds of the array and access some surprising numbers.